# Range based for loop with pointer to vector in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Consider the following example:

```
vector<vector<char>*> *outer = new vector<vector<char>*>();
{
    vector<char> *inner = new vector<char>();

    inner->push_back(0);
    inner->push_back(1);
    inner->push_back(2);

    outer->push_back(inner);

    inner->push_back(3);
}

auto x = outer->at(0);

for (auto c : x) {
    cout << c << ",";
}
```

I would like to iterate through the values of the `vector<char>*`; how can I accomplish that?

Comment: This is terrible, terrible code. At the very least, use `unique_ptr` rather than owning raw pointers. Better yet, get rid of the unnecessary `new`s altogether.

Comment: The last time I opened book on C++ which was roughly before C++98 such code would be normal... ))) Thank you, will go through `unique_ptr`...

Comment: Basically it's not even about the raw pointers. It's about using `new` in the first place.

Comment: It was used to illustrate the problem, however what's wrong with it (in general)?

Comment: Use vector<vector<char>> outer;  instead of that vector<vector<char>*> *outer = new vector<vector<char>*>();

Comment: I'm afraid to incidentally copy the vector when for example doing the following: `for (auto x : vector_vector_var) { ... }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you simply dereference `x`?

```
for (auto c : *x) { // Here
    cout << c << ",";
}
```

It will take `*x`by reference and, so, won't make a copy.

Comment: will it produce the copy of the original vector?

Comment: No, it won't. It will take it by reference.

Comment: @Telokis " It will take it by reference."  any reference for this point?thx

Answer (score 3):

The type of `x` is `vector<char>*` so you need to iterate over what is pointed to by `x`; you need to dereference `x`.

```
for (auto&& c : *x) {
//              ^ dereference the container for a range
//       ^ note the use of &&
```

As a side note;

- the characters for the integer values `0`, `1` etc. are not printable, I'd test with `0x31` etc or just push back characters `'0'`, `'1'` etc.
- it is generally preferable to use `auto&&` in the range based for loops to avoid copies or subtle bugs when the container returns proxy object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "Hello Lu4";
    std::vector<std::vector<char> *> *v = 
        new std::vector<std::vector<char> *>( 1, new std::vector<char>( s, s + std::strlen( s ) ) );

    for ( char c : *( *v )[0] ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( auto p : *v ) delete p;
    delete v;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello Lu4
```

Also you could use the following loop

```
for ( auto inner : *v )
{
    for ( char c : *inner ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If to use this loop in the demonstrative program you will get the same result as above because the "outer" vector contains only one element with index 0.